# Monomorphisms in homotopy categories

Tags: homotopy-theory

In **hTop**, insertions into coproducts $i : X \to X \amalg Y$ are monomorphisms, since, for any $f,g : Z \to X$ such that $if \simeq ig$, the homotopy factors through $i$ and thus $f \simeq g$.

This meshes well with the fact the monomorphisms in the $\infty$-category of spaces are precisely those whose class in in **hTop** are of the above form. Or a similar statement for the homotopy monomorphisms of **Top** (or other model). This prompts the question

> **Question 1:** Are *all* of the monomorphisms in **hTop** in the form? (i.e. the insertion into a coproduct or equivalently the class of a homotopy monomorphism from **Top** or equivalently the class of a monomorphism in the $\infty$-category of spaces)

Assuming the answer is affirmative, my next question is when we can make similar assertions in the more general case:

> **Question 2:** For a model category **M**, when can we say the monomorphisms in **Ho**(**M**) are precisely the (classes of) homotopy monomorphisms in **M**?
>
> **Question 3:** For an $\infty$-category *M*, when can we say the monomorphisms in **Ho**(*M*) are precisely the (classes of) monomorphisms in *M*?

Comment: "...of this form" -- of which form? ##### Could you write your questions in a stand-alone style?

Comment: If $X$ is the terminal object in hTop (a one-point space), then any map $X\to Y$ is a monomorphism

Comment: @TomGoodwillie Ah, of course! I'm now glad I was skeptical of my calculation enough to ask... now to figure out where it went wrong....

Comment: I can't self-delete the question.

Comment: Can you edit the question?